# Physical realization of qubits with superconducting Josephson junctions

Tags: experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

Does anybody know how to explain briefly how to realize qubits (initialization, states transition, measurements,..) with superconducting Josephson junctions, say DC-SQUIDS?

Comment: This is pretty good https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Superconducting_quantum_computing&action=submit

Comment: Definitely but before it's worth 50 pt reputation here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the subject matter of supercondcuting qubits is rather broad and diverse, making it challenging to accurately capture it in a 'brief explanation'.

With that said, this [recent review](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5089550?class=pdf) (Krantz et al., Applied Physics Reviews **6**, 021318 (2019)) - "A Quantum Engineer's Guide to Superconducting Qubits" ([arXiv:1904.06560](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.06560.pdf)) from the MIT group may be a good place to start.

Section II in the article is perhaps the most relevant to this question, as it describes several implementations of superconducting qubits, from the transmon and tunable transmon to flux qubits and fluxonium. The article further discusses, in sections IV and V, the state of the art in terms of control and readout.

The article does not discuss charge- and phase-qubits, which were abandoned (for the most part) because of their higher sensitivity to noise and material losses.

Comment: Please add some of the info from the link, as this currently is a link-only answer. If the link dies, none of the information will be retained. (At least start with the name and authors of the review, perhaps?)